# How can I show a prediction of trained images in subfolders for such as face mask or no face mask using colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Using colab

[The image is folder and inside it is subfolders and inside it are images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfu6u.jpg)

```
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=2e-4),
          metrics=['acc'])
   history = model.fit(train_generator,
                          batch_size=64,
                          epochs=10)
   model.save('model.h5')
```

Comment: from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('Cars_updated')
base_dir='Cars_updated'

Comment: train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(base_dir,
                                              target_size=(150,150),
                                              batch_size=64,
                                              class_mode='categorical',
                                              subset='training')